# bootstrap tooltip works with one button but not with other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap tooltip i defined as follows:

```
<button id="tooltip1" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" 
                        data-toggle="tooltip" 
                        data-placement="right" 
                        data-original-title="Add a Program"
                        ng-click="display.addprogram = true">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign pull-right"></span>
                    </button>

<button id="tooltip1" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right"
                                    data-toggle="tooltip" 
                                    data-placement="right" 
                                    data-original-title="Add a Course"
                                    ng-show="{{node.min_credit}} != summedcompleted[{{node.id}}]"
                                    ng-click="open({{node.id}}, {{node.min_credit}}, summedcompleted[{{node.id}}], summedplanned[{{node.id}}])"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign pull-right"></span>
                            </button>

<script id="tooltipid" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tooltip1').tooltip();
            });
        </script>
```

The tooltip works well only with the first button but not with the second one. What might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML IDs must be unique.  You have two elements with the ID `tooltip1`, which isn't legal.  You should perhaps use a class instead, for instance:

```
$('.btn').tooltip();
```

Comment: Using `$('.btn')` may be just a little too generic though.

Comment: @NigelAngel: Sure, in which case add a new class only to those buttons that need tooltips.